# how to load int value to the textfield and display on label on another collection view controller

Tags: ios, storyboard, uicollectionview

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (indexPath.item > 0 ) 
     {
       myNumber = indexPath.item;
       NSLog(@"Item is %i", myNumber);

       NSString *myNewString = [@(myNumber) stringValue];
       [txt setText:myNewString];

       self.datastring=txt.text;

       WeddingViewController *wed=[[WeddingViewController alloc]init];
       [self presentViewController:wed animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

and in the `viewDidLoad` of second collection view.....

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.lbl.text =self.datastring;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom constructor (init) method for your WeddingViewController like this along with a property to hold that value:

Inside your `WeddingViewController.h` file, create the constructor method:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int storedIntValue;

-(id)initWithValue:(int)intValue;
```

Then in your implementation file, you can go:

```
-(id)initWithValue:(int)intValue
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        self.storedIntValue = intValue;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    ....

    self.lbl.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", self.storedIntValue];
}
```

Finally, where you push the WeddingViewController, you can go:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (indexPath.item > 0 ) 
     {
       myNumber = indexPath.item;
       NSLog(@"Item is %i", myNumber);

       NSString *myNewString = [@(myNumber) stringValue];
       [txt setText:myNewString];

       self.datastring=txt.text;

       // ----------------------------------------------------
       // Notice use of the "initWithIntValue:" method
       //
       // note: is myNumber meant to be indexPath row ? 
       // ----------------------------------------------------
       WeddingViewController *wed=[[WeddingViewController alloc] initWithValue:myNumber];
       [self presentViewController:wed animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the alternative is to store that int value somewhere in your application that can be accessed globally, such as a singleton, or if it's a user defaults thing, you can use:

```
// save value into NSUserDefaults if it's appropriate
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:3] forKey:@"myIntValue"];
[NSUserDefaults synchronize];

// get value from NSUserDefaults
int myIntValue = [[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] valueForKey:@"myIntValue"] integerValue];
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do this way,you can make  string property in WeddingViewController.h and acccess it in viewDidLoad direct ,

```
 @property (nonatomic, assign) NSString dataString;
```

and in viewWillAppear

```
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     self.lbl.text = dataString;
    }

    and when make WeddingViewController object give property like this,      

    WeddingViewController *wed=[[WeddingViewController alloc]init];
    wed.dataString = dataString;
    [self presentViewController:wed animated:YES completion:nil];
```